# Error in starting Android activity

Tags: android, android-activity, runtime-error, android-logcat

In the MainActivity class within a switch statement I declared and initialised an Intent to begin another activity. Here is the snippet:

```
case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                //save connected device name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "+mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent medPlay = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MediaPlayer.class);
                startActivity(medPlay);
                break;
```

Here is the MediaPlayer class:

```
public class MediaPlayer extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.media_player);
    }
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bt"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="6"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bt.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/select_device"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MediaPlayer"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/media_player"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

However I keep getting this error on LogCat Console:

> 12-31 12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-31 12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.example.bt/android.media.MediaPlayer}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 12-31
>   12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
>   12-31 12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
>   12-31 12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):  at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2893) 12-31
>   12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):    at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3003) 12-31
>   12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):    at
>   com.example.bt.MainActivity$1.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:147)
>   12-31 12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-31
>   12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 12-31 12:39:52.475:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25978):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806) 12-31
>   12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-31
>   12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 12-31 12:39:52.475:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(25978):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   12-31 12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 12-31
>   12:39:52.475: E/AndroidRuntime(25978):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Start Activity code as:

```
Intent medPlay = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                               com.example.bt.MediaPlayer.class);
startActivity(medPlay);
```

and declare MediaPlayer as in AndroidManifest as :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.bt.MediaPlayer"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/media_player"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" />
```

because as in log messages :

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.example.bt/android.media.MediaPlayer}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

system is trying to start default `MediaPlayer` Activity

Comment: @prosper: Is there any default MeduaPlayer Activity.? BTW, Its new year. Go enjoy it.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj : Happy new year Sahil :)

Comment: @user1909680 : my answer help you in solving current issue or not?

Comment: @prosper ha ha. well I up voted it but forgot to add my comment to your answer too. No hard feelings,.

Comment: @AndroSelva : haha i just want to say you "HAPPY NEW YEAR" that's why i comment u.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.bt/**android.media.MediaPlayer**};

You have imported/specified the wrong MediaPlayer!

Comment: Excellent Catch. just Rename your Activity or remove the MediaPlayer from the imports. And it should work.